# Creating a median filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, median

I am given an image that has "speckle noise", my assignment is to remove in each layer separately then recombining the clean image. I am not allowed to use the med2flt() only the median filter. I have already separated the 3 different layers red,green and blue but I do not know how to apply the median filter to them. How would I do it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `colfilt` or `nlfilter`?  The problem is very very easy with these functions.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `nlfilter`**

If you're allowed to use `nlfilter`, you could give it a try with `flt = @(x) median(x(:))` as its filter function. You find more information on this if you type `doc nlfilter`.

**Writing your own**

It could be that the exercise is about how to implement a filtering operation yourself. First, you may want to allocate memory for the filtered image with `imf = zeros(size(im, 1) - 2, size(im, 2) - 2);` That image is a little smaller because one way to handle the edges is to discard them. Then, consider two `for` loops over `x` and `y` for image `im` as in

```
for x = 1 : size(im, 2) - 2
    for y = 1 : size(im, 1) - 2
        roi = im(y : y + 2, x : x + 2);
        imf(y, x) = median(roi(:));
    end
end
```

`roi` keeps the local 3x3 neighborhood of `im`, and `median(roi(:))` allows you to calculate the median of those 9 intensity values.